# fix the base mesh for a good subdivision

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

[image]

Can anyone tell me what are the defects of this mesh?

i want to apply modifier subdivision and i am not getting results.
especially when applying a curvature map.
the problem occurs trying to apply the curvature map both before and after applying the modifier subdivision .
the curvature map is wrinkled.

I know the mesh has defects, but I don't know which ones and where they are.

above follows the mesh file for download without applying the subdivision modifier and the bevel modifiers.

thanks

[image]

Comment: Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: the file is at the top of the message.
are you not seeing there?

Comment: Doh.  I've gotten so used to looking at the bottom, I scrolled right by it.  Sorry.

Comment: The hardops vertex groups from the bevel modifiers are missing.  Do you want an analysis with the bevels deleted? (The quick answer is that you've created too many n-gons, especially tris, trying to connect the depressions.  I think you'd be better off using control loops and dramatically reducing the 3-gons

Comment: Could you, if possible, show images of the errors I should fix?

Comment: is there any tool or addon that makes it easier to see the overlapping vertices?
is it appropriate to subtract all tris? Or can I leave some, like the ones that make up the planes destined for the bevel?what do you mean by : The hardops vertex groups from the bevel modifiers are missing ?

Comment: To find and fix overlapping vertices go to edit mode, select all, type M to bring up the merge menu and select _by distance_ from the menu.  There's no simple answer to what tris to delete.  You're trading 3-gons for poles with 5 or more edges and it depends a lot on the supporting geometry.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small problem with overlapping vertices that you can fix in edit mode by typing the <kbd>M</kbd> key and selecting *by distance* from the menu that pops up.

Mostly though, your attempts to support the rounded corners have produced a lot of 3-gons, and giving this geometry I think you'd be better with a lot fewer of those and using control loops instead.

Here's a sample of the lower indented area showing most of the problems resolved.  It has a Subsurf but none of the Bevel modifiers as your original file doesn't have the vertex groups for those modifiers:

[image: Sample of removing tries and using control loops]

It's not perfect, and you'll have to make more adjustments when you have your bevels where you want them; but I usually have much better luck with this approach.

Comment: is it appropriate to leave vertices without edges? is to simply delete: dissolve the edges?

Comment: It's not appropriate to leave vertices without edges.  If you dissolve edges you will also remove any vertices that lay on those edges.  You can see this in the above example, where I removed several edges from the upper right area.

Comment: is there a more automatic way to subtract the tris? maybe some addon?

Comment: You can try using the tris-to-quads command; but at most it will only remove a few.  (IIRC the shortcut is ALT-J)